# SQL query display last row by a column

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to display all information submitted by a specific username(variable) in my case:

```
<?php
$Username = $_SESSION['VALID_USER_ID'];

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `article_table` ORDER BY FIELD (Username, '.$Username.') DESC LIMIT 1");
while($db = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { ?>

Your Articles: <?=$db['Subject'];?><br />

<? } ?>
```

But don't work, I'll display the last article subject(for example) from the table and not from the specific username, where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how ORDER BY works. You first need to filter the results by using the WHERE clause.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `article_table` WHERE `Username` = '$Username' ORDER BY `other_column` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Replace `other_colum` in this query by the name of your date column: ie. `date_created`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `article_table`
ORDER BY FIELD (Username, '.$Username.') DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This should be returning the username you are looking for when it is available.  The logic is that field returns 1 when the name matches and 0 otherwise.  So the descending keyword puts the match first.  If there is no match, then you will get another row.

Presumably the data does not exist.  You can test that easily enough by running:

```
SELECT *
FROM `article_table`
WHERE Username = '.$Username.';
```